# unexpected token in json file Angular 4

Tags: json, spring, angular, httprequest

I'm using Angular 4 and Spring framework to create my project. and this is my problem

{error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token A in JSON at position 0 at JSON.parse () at XMLHttp…, text: "AAA"}

I want to read the string AAA but the console show me  this error.

My backend code:

```
@PostMapping(value = "login")
public ResponseEntity<?> verifyLogin(@RequestBody String login){
    System.out.println("LOGIN REALIZADO");
    LoginObject loginO = gson.fromJson(login, LoginObject.class);

    if(verify(loginO)){
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("AAA",HttpStatus.OK);
    }else{
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("ERROR-LOGIN",HttpStatus.OK);
    }


}
```

My frontend service:

```
export class LoginService{

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

     loginQuery(login: Login):Observable<string>{
        return this.http.post<string>(this.url,JSON.stringify(login));
     }
}
```

and my frontend

onSingin(form: NgForm){

```
if( (form.value.code !== '') && (form.value.password !== '')){
  this.loginService.loginQuery(new Login(form.value.code, form.value.password)).
  subscribe(
    result => this.verifyLogin(result.toString())
   );
}
}
```

when I call the verifyLogin the console show me the error

Comment: Well, AAA is not valid JSON, and you're telling HttpClient that you expect JSON. Time to read the documentation: https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
export class LoginService{

  private url = 'http://localhost:8080/login';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient){}

     loginQuery(login: Login):Observable<string>{
        // Your previous code:
        // return this.http.post<string>(this.url,JSON.stringify(login));
        
        // Updated with details from (https://angular.io/guide/http#requesting-non-json-data)
        return this.http.post<string>(this.url, JSON.stringify(login), {responseType: 'text'});
     }
}
```

Comment: @LucasAlves => If this is working for you, can you please accept it as the answer so that others viewing the page in the future will know that?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using simple string `AAA` which is not a valid `Json` Use map of string in `ResponseEntity<Map<String, String>>`